# Tooltip in Jface tree

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

I have a jface tree without columnviewer support. It has a decorating label provider as i need to decorate the tree items. I cannot use a celllableprovider to do this. I have seen the examples such as http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet015CustomTooltipsForTree.java?view=markup but it does not suffice my requirement as i cannot use the celllabelprovider. How do I get tooltips for my tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that the following way does the work:

http://davymeers.net/2010/07/04/jface-using-columnviewers-combined-with-decoration-and-custom-tooltips/